# How to use associated type in the method declaration

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I am building a generic method for parsing server responses. Probably I want to do it too fancy way, but in another hand I will use it in many projects so maybe it is worth to spend some time on it, Let's describe the problem I have.

I implemented response skeleton which is a generic class from where I will create objects. The objects are the type of M

```
class ApiResponse<M: Mappable> {  
    required init(response: Any) {
        // Here I'd like to do mapping according to the holding type
    }
}
```

And then for each endpoint I created class which defines what type of objects server returns

```
class PostsResponse: ApiResponse<Post> {

}
```

The api client has methods for each endpoint which determine the response type, so every type is know from now. Here is and example:

```
var posts: Observable<PostsResponse> {
    get { return getObservable(endpoint: .posts) }
}
```

So far so good. The problem starts here when I am creating "Swifty" method for getting observers (see below). `ApiResponse` is a generic type, so in the declaration of `getObservable` the compiler wants to know exact type and the second problem is when I call constructor of the `Response` class, because somehow `T` has no accessible initialisers.

```
private func getObservable<T>(endpoint: Endpoint) -> Observable<T> where T:ApiResponse {
    return Observable.create({ observer -> Disposable in
        Alamofire
            .request(endpoint.url, method: .get)
            .responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let json):
                    let parsedResponse = T(response: json)
                    observer.onNext(parsedResponse)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                case .failure(let error):
                    observer.onError(error)
                }
            })
        return Disposables.create()
    })
}
```

The question is how to make comiler happy.

Here is a link to the code https://github.com/artur-gurgul/babylon-partners

---

### Update

After hours of fighting with this issue I have made it working, however I found something strange.

I wrote the method signature as fallowing

```
private func getObservable<T: ApiResponse<A>, A: Mappable>(endpoint: Endpoint, t:A?=nil) -> Observable<T> where A:NSManagedObject
```

When I remove `t:A?=nil` the compiler is unhappy. It complains that `A` type is not used in the method signature. Why it is so?, why? why? why?

Answer (score 0):

This seems likely to be a deficiency / limitation with the current implementation of type inference in the Swift compiler. While it is logical to expect the compiler to be able to infer two nested levels of generic type constraints (`A` and `T`) in your example, I'm guessing that this sort of multi-level inference isn't implemented right now, meaning that Swift expects you to use all generic type constraints in the signature itself, so the compiler can infer from the context of any calling code what `A` and `T` should be without requiring more than one level of solving, e.g. without requiring that it understand that:

```
result = PostResponse             <----->    T = PostResponse

PostResponse: ApiResponse<Post>   <----->    T: ApiResponse<Post>

Post is the inner generic type    <----->    therefore A: Post
```

Instead, you have to give Swift a direct contextual way to infer `A` without having to first infer and introspect on `T`.

Your solution above does provide `A` in the signature, which silences the compiler (though I don't think this approach will actually work, see my second note further down).  A more conventional approach is to require the code that calls you function to explicitly specify the type for `A` as a parameter, e.g.:

```
private func getObservable<T: ApiResponse<A>, A: Mappable>(endpoint: Endpoint, objectType:A.Type) -> Observable<T> where A:NSManagedObject
```

This would get called in your code like this:

```
var posts: Observable<PostsResponse> {
    get { return getObservable(endpoint: .posts, objectType:Post.self) }
}
```

A couple of side notes:

1. I don't think you need to specify the `A:Mappable` constraint since the class declaration `class ApiResponse<M:Mappable>` already declares that requirement
2. Even though your workaround example where you have a parameter with a nil  default value (`t:A? = nil`) silences the compiler warning, I would be surprised if you didn't get a different warning if you tried to actually call the function somewhere in your code. The nil default value for the parameter `t:A?` makes the compiler unable to infer directly what concrete type `A` should be, and I said noted earlier, I don't think the Swift compiler is able to otherwise infer `A` by first inferring and then introspecting on `T`.